# Global well posedness of $\phi^4_1$

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-calculus

We consider the $\phi^4_1$ model: $\partial_t\phi=\Delta\phi-\phi^3+\xi$ on $[0,T] \times \mathbb{R},$ where $\xi$ is a space time white noise.

I know how to solve this equation locally on the torus, see for example Hairer lecture notes on SPDE.

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain the global well-posedness of the equation on the real line. If so, how? (On $\mathbb{R}^2$ we need to define weighted Holder-Besov spaces)